# Receive an automatic Email if I sent an email to a wrong email

Tags: email

In outlook, if I send an email to a wrong email, I receive an automatic email informing of the error.
Is it possible to send an automatic email, when I sent a message on incorrect email via apex?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's email servers will automatically send an email back to your inbox by default. If you enable [Bounce Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5), and you use a Contact or Lead record to send the email, the email address will automatically be flagged in the UI.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But in my case, I press the button on Account object, email field for this account is chosen and Email is sent. All logic realized in apex. I use try/catch to execute exception, but if the message already is sent how can I know, either it reaches the recipient (for example, if email field contains unexistence email) on not.

Comment: @Artur The bounces should be sent to wherever the reply-to was set to. By default, that's your user account. Check the code to see if a reply-to is set.

Comment: @Artur Oh, in your Apex, you have no way to tell. The email is *queued* to be sent when you call Messaging.sendEmail, but it will *not* be sent until after the transaction fully commits. The only way to know is to check your email afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use Messaging.SendEmailResult for this purpose? But, as I know it not guarantee that message will find endpoint (if email is wrong),  Or I wrong? In official documentation said: _Even if success = true, it does not mean the intended recipients received the email, as it could have bounced or been blocked by a spam blocker. Also, even if the email is successfully accepted for delivery by the message transfer agent, there can still be errors in the error array related to individual addresses within the email._

Comment: @Artur No, Messaging.SendEmailResult tells you only that the email was queued for delivery to the recipients, not that it was received.

Comment: So, I cannot check it from salesforce side. That's a pity. @sfdcfox Thanks for your help!!!